# Generate APIDocuments easily from Prisma Client in Conduit Dart Server

Tags: flutter, openapi, code-generation, conduit, dart-server

I've built dart-server using conduit frameworks and prisma package.
I'd like to generate api specifications using conduit document command.
The api endpoints are using lots of prisma schemas and need to extends Serializable for api specification.
Do I have to make new classes extending "Serializable" for all prisma schemas or are there any easy way to implement it?

I've made a new class for prisma schema extending "Serializable" for openapi specification.
I'm expecting easy way to do this.